# Live Reload of SCSS in React JS using Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I would like to ask if there's a way that the compiling of .scss file to .css is included in webpack hot reload, I use to always run npm run build to convert my .scss to .css

Here's my webpack.config:

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/main.js',
    output: {
        path: './',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 3333
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: '/node_modules/',
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015','react']
                }
            },
            {
                 test: /\.scss$/,
                 loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!sass-loader")
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css',{
            allChunks: false
        })
    ],
    postcss: [
        autoprefixer({
          browsers: ['last 2 versions']
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: show us your webpack config.

Comment: @QoP - added webpack config

Comment: Have you tried to remove ExtractPluginText for development? It doesn't support hot reload.